# Keyboard hides the text filed in the master UITableViewController when using UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, keyboard, uisplitview

Normally UITableViewController in iOS comes with the functionality of auto-scrolling the content to account for the active textfield, when keyboard is shown. But this feature stops working when adding the UITableViewController as a master page for UISplitViewController.

Can anyone helps me in solving this issue.

Here is a youtube link that I just found while googling, which shows this weird behaviour:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4rcB8lzcpU